# Heroku single account error: "Your account email@address.com does not have access to oldappname. SSH Key Fingerprint: XXX..."

Tags: git, heroku, github, ssh

I have a repository on github and heroku, both of which have been renamed.  When I `git push heroku master`, I get the error

```
!  Your account email@address.com does not have access to oldappname.
!  
!  SSH Key Fingerprint: XXX. . .
```

Thanks for any pointers!  I'm looking forward to being able to move past this error.

*A similar question has been asked many times, always for users with multiple Heroku accounts, but I have only one Heroku account.  Because the solutions to the multiple accounts questions (adding, deleting ssh keys) haven't worked for my problem, I'm making this its own question.

Comment: I honestly don't understand the downvote; could somebody explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to get past this error!  In the terminal, I ran

```
git remote -v
```

which produced

```
heroku  git@heroku.com:rainbow.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:rainbow.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/username/rainbows-rainbows.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/username/rainbows-rainbows.git (push)
```

The app names don't match! Heroku was still checking for the git repository under its old name.  To fix this, I ran

```
git remote rm heroku
```

thus removing the incorrect heroku remotes.  On Heroku, I deleted the repository (perhaps not necessary, but I wanted a fresh start unburdened by incomplete name changes).  So to initialize the app in Heroku, I ran

```
heroku create newappname
```

and finally, my

```
git push heroku master
```

succeeded.

Comment: Thank you so much for the update. I ran into the same issue!